# Forge Veiwer flickering textures

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We're experiencing a heavy amount of flickering textures after applying baked textures onto our model.

We're thinking that this could have something to do with which sides of the faces that are rendered.

Are we able to access existing material and change properties like material side?
Or, could there be any other reason for the heavy flickering?

Answer (score 0):

Under `Settings`, can you try to turn off `Progressive display`?

[image]